# INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and INSERT IGNORE transaction issue

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.6

I have a reproduction where INSERTing a row doesn't actually seem to insert them, if you follow a transaction.

Reproduction using docker (I've reproduced on 10.5 and 10.6):

```sh
docker run -d -e MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=toor -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=toor --name mariadb_perf_test_10_6 mariadb:10.6
```

Then log in twice:

```sh
docker exec -it mariadb_perf_test_10_5 mysql -u root -ptoor
```

In session 1, set up the data:

```sql
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS transaction_interference_test;
CREATE DATABASE transaction_interference_test;
USE transaction_interference_test;
CREATE TABLE read_uncommit (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  rk1 INTEGER UNSIGNED,
  rk2 INTEGER UNSIGNED,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  UNIQUE KEY (rk1, rk2)
);
CREATE TABLE unrelated_data (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
INSERT INTO unrelated_data VALUES (1, 'hi');
```

In both sessions:

```sql
USE transaction_interference_test;  
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM unrelated_data;
```

Then again, in both sessions (one of them will hang):

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO read_uncommit (rk1, rk2) VALUES (1, 1);
```

(ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE has the same effect)

In the session that didn't hang:

```sql
COMMIT;
```

In the session that did hang:

```sql
SHOW WARNINGS;
SELECT * FROM read_uncommit;
```

If you follow the second session (that hung for a bit waiting for the COMMIT), it seems like you INSERTed a row, actually got a warning to indicate that yes, the row exists, but if you try to query it, it won't show.

I'm guessing this is related to phantom reads somehow?

My question then: is there a safer way to ensure that a row exists?

Comment: What transaction isolation mode?

Comment: The default is `REPEATABLE READ`. So the subsequent selects will return the results previously observed. Yes the warnings from insert ignore show a leak of data changed into the isolation level, but I can't think of a better behaviour. If you are `select`ing and then deciding to `insert ignore` this is adding a race condition.

Comment: Yeah, it's the default `REPEATABLE READ`. Not sure what the performance impact will be if I raise it to `SERIALIZABLE`, or whether that'll help at all.

Comment: What is the use case you are trying to solve?

Comment: In this case, we try to track login attempts, to prevent people from brute forcing a password. So we keep a table with a counter and a unique key; if it doesn't exist, create a row with counter 1, and if it does exist, we need to increase the counter by one